# How do I connect to a hidden SSID in Windows 10 programmatically?

Tags: .net, windows, uwp, wifi

I have spent ages on this and I am stuck.
I am trying to connect to a known hidden SSID programmatically.

I am using the following code

```
await firstAdapter.ScanAsync();

WiFiAvailableNetwork network = firstAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Ssid == ssid);
```

The problem is I need to supply as a first an object of type `WiFiAvailableNetwork`  but `AvailableNetworks` only brings back non-hidden SSIDs.

```
public IAsyncOperation<WiFiConnectionResult> ConnectAsync(WiFiAvailableNetwork availableNetwork, WiFiReconnectionKind reconnectionKind, PasswordCredential passwordCredential, String ssid)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter.connectasync#Windows_Devices_WiFi_WiFiAdapter_ConnectAsync_Windows_Devices_WiFi_WiFiAvailableNetwork_Windows_Devices_WiFi_WiFiReconnectionKind_Windows_Security_Credentials_PasswordCredential_System_String_

The above code works perfectly with non-hidden SSID's.
Is there an API to connect to a hidden SSID?
Thanks

Comment: It does not look there is a way to do that except try to create profile for the network and the connect with using profile. Not sure if there is even WiFi profile management functions available in WinRT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If available, the hidden network should be in the `firstAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks` list.

As the SSID is hidden, the `Ssid` property of `WiFiAvailableNetwork` for the target network will be `""`.

You could make an assumption here and attempt to connect to it using:

`await firstAdapter.ConnectAsync(networks.First(x => x.Ssid == ""), WiFiReconnectionKind.Automatic, "password", "knownSSID");`

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for ++++++++